# Fundamental group of a compact hyperbolic manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact hyperbolic manifold, and $\tilde M = H^n$ the universal covering.
Now let $\Gamma$ be the group of Decktransformations.  So we have $\tilde M / \Gamma = M$.

My question: Is it possible, that all $g \in \Gamma$ have one common fixpoint at infinity?

I know that all $g \in \Gamma$ are of hyperbolic type, so they have two fixpoints at infinity.
If we look at this in the Poincaré-ball model of the hyperbolic space, we have or each $g \in \Gamma$ two points $p_1$, $p_2 \in \partial B^n$ with $g(p_1) = p_1$ and $g(p_2)=p_2$.
So could there exist a point $p \in \partial B^n$ such that $g(p) = p$ for all $g \in \Gamma$?

I think the answer is no, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is straightforward to show to show that if two hyperbolics have exactly one common fixed point, then the subgroup they generate is not discrete; actually, that is also the case if one of them is a parabolic. Don't take my word for it and check that this is true!

I think you can conclude from there?

Comment: I think you are right. I did not realize that two geodesics with a commmon endpoint at infinity "approach each other" while going toward this point. So one can argument with "discrete subgroup" or that this is in 'M' not possible because such a geodesic in '\tilde{M}' is a closed geodesic in 'M' and two of them can not approach each other.